# How can I run a python script using lighttpd fast-cgi with pyenv?

Tags: fastcgi, lighttpd, pythonbrew

I am running the script with my own user:

```
# from /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

server.document-root        = "/opt/app/current/bin/"
server.username             = "klenwell"

fastcgi.server  = (
    ".py" => (
        "localhost" => (
            "socket" => "/tmp/klenwell-fastcgi.socket",
            "bin-path" => "/opt/app/current/bin/app.py",
            "max-procs" => 5
        )
    )
)
```

In my python script, I have the shebang set like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

But when I run the script, I get an error stating it can't load a module I installed with pip. This indicates that it is using system python rather than the pyenv version.

```
/usr/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf start
(traceback omitted)
ImportError: No module named requests
```

If I change the shebang to use the pyenv python install explicitly, like so:

```
#!/home/klenwell/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/bin/python
```

I am able start lighttpd successfully.

Currently, the same basic configuration is successfully running the web application using pythonbrew rather than pyenv. But since pythonbrew has been deprecated, I am trying to migrate to pyenv. Any ideas on how to configure lighttpd so that it successfully loads pyenv for my user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague figured this out. It required adding the pyenv paths to the `PATH` variable under `bin-environment`. For example:

```
fastcgi.server  = (
    ".py" => (
        "localhost" => (
            "socket" => "/tmp/klenwell-fastcgi.socket",
            "bin-path" => "/opt/app/current/bin/app.py",
            "bin-copy-environment" => (""),
            "bin-environment" => (
              "PATH" => "/home/klenwell/.pyenv/shims:/home/klenwell/.pyenv/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
            ),
            "max-procs" => 5
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: how did you do that?

Comment: how can i contact you ?